# Maven dependency scope conflict with Eclipse scope

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, dependencies

When I declare maven dependancy in Eclipse as `runtime`, then additional jar's are copied to tomcat on deployment. On `compile` I have deployment errors, because absence of libraries. Eclipse always compiles without errors.

But, when I want to build the same project only with Maven (`mvn compile`), the **`runtime` dependencies are not in classpath when compiling**, so I have compilation errors.

This causes that I have to compile only with one of those tools or to maintain two `pom.xml` files.

Any solution on `pom.xml` dependencies to be both used in `mvn` command compilation and deployed to runtime environment with Eclipse?

Comment: If you provide some additional information, it will be easier to help. What are your compilation errors? What is in your Eclipse .classpath? What dependencies are in your pom? Do the two match?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you declare your dependencies as `runtime` if they are needed for compilation?

```
runtime
This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.
```

Comment: Eclipse don't deploy it together with project classes&JSP to tomcat if I set `compile` scope. With `runtime` - it does.